# Is there anyway to test run EDIDisassembler component with pipeline testing tool?

Tags: biztalk, edi, biztalk-2013

First, Let me explain why I need do this.

I have an inbound port with EDIReceive Pipeline configuration. it receives EDI X12 837I files and disassemble these files to 837I messages.

There's one file failed with error description below:

> The following elements are not closed: ns0:X12_00501_837_I. Line 1, position 829925.

It looks like the incoming file have some structure issue. Making the disassembler cannot produce the message correctly.  But the error itself don't help to locate the issue. Also, no TA1 and 999 generated to help us locate the issue.

So I created a little console application using the [Pipeline Component Test Library](https://github.com/tomasr/pipelinetesting) try to run this file through the edidisassembler pipeline component to see if I can find what cause the error.

The code is pretty straightforward:

```
namespace TestEDIDasm
{
    using System;
    using System.IO;
    using Microsoft.BizTalk.Edi.Pipelines;
    using Microsoft.BizTalk.Message.Interop;
    using Winterdom.BizTalk.PipelineTesting;
    using Microsoft.BizTalk.Edi.BatchMarker;

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var ediDasmComp = new EdiDisassembler();
            ediDasmComp.UseIsa11AsRepetitionSeparator = true;
            ediDasmComp.XmlSchemaValidation = true;
            var batchMaker = new PartyBatchMarker();
            IBaseMessage testingMessage = MessageHelper.LoadMessage(@"c:\temp\{1C9420EB-5C54-43E5-9D9D-7297DE65B36C}_context.xml");
            ReceivePipelineWrapper testPipelineWrapper = PipelineFactory.CreateEmptyReceivePipeline();
            testPipelineWrapper.AddComponent(ediDasmComp, PipelineStage.Disassemble);
            testPipelineWrapper.AddComponent(batchMaker, PipelineStage.ResolveParty);
            var outputMessages = testPipelineWrapper.Execute(testingMessage);
            if (outputMessages.Count <= 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("No output message");
                Console.ReadKey();
                return;
            }
            var msg = outputMessages[0];
            StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(msg.BodyPart.Data);
            Console.WriteLine(sr.ReadToEnd());
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

I added some breakpoint but end up with following errors in message context:

> "X12 service schema not found"

Clearly, the EDIDisassembler component rely on some other stuff to do its job.

Now goes to my question:

1. Is there anyway to make EdiDisassembler working in testing
   environment?
2. If there any other way to debug/trace the disassembler component
       processing file other than  Pipeline Component Test Library?

Answer (score 0):

Theoretically, sure, but you have to replicate a lot of engine context that exists during Pipeline execution.  The EDI components have issues running inside Orchestrations so it's likely a pretty tall order.

Have you tried a Preserve Interchange Pipeline with the Fallback Settings?  That's about as simple as you can get with the EDI Disassembler.

Comment: Not sure what you mean on "Preserve Interchange Pipeline with the Fallback Settings". Could you give some more detail on this?

Comment: On the EDI Disassembler, set Preserve interchange to True.

Comment: Just have a try. Same result.

Comment: Did you look at the segment at 829925?  You may have to start counting from the ST.  Similarly, you can test the ST...SE in Visual Studio against the Schema.

Comment: The total file size is only 60K. So I believe this position is the position in generated xml content, not the  original EDI content.

Comment: Yes, you're right, there's another message for the EDI position.  Did you Validate the 837 ST in Visual Studio?

Comment: Yes, I did. There're lots of validation errors but no hint on which error cause the element not closed error.